# Does compactly supported cohomology make sense for cosimplicial spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, homology

As far as I understand, whenever one has something (co)simplicial in spaces, one should take a sort of diagonal to reduce the study to a single space. I'm never sure though whether one preserves only the whole *homotopic* information or really the homeomorphic type.

My real question is the following: If $X^\bullet_\bullet$ is a simplicial object in cosimplicial spaces, does it make sense to speak about its **Borel-Moore homology**? Is it a limit/colimit of BM homologies? Does it matter in which order I take the diagonals/Tots/realisations?

I'm trying to get my multi(co)simplicial facts straight.

Comment: I find this question somewhat unclear, the BM-homology is defined for locally finite simplicial complexes, right? Not even for simplicial sets in general.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: OK, let's say I have a cosimiplicial space, which at each level is homeomorphic to a locally finite simplicial complex. Can I define BM homology for that?

Comment: John, probably you can, but maybe you want your definition to satisfy some properties, and hopefully *that* would lead you to an appropriate definition.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I was hoping people smarter than me had already thought about it, that's why I asked. In general, is there a good place to read about cosimplicial spaces? What about simplicial-cosimplicial ones?

Comment: I don't really have any nice suggestion. I'd like to be able to say something like: take levelwise the complex of locally finite chains, in an ideal world this would give rise to a cosimplicial chain complex, then totalize, and consider the homology of that complex. The problem is that I think that assuming each space to be a locally compact polyhedron doesn't help that much because the chain complex of locally finite chains I think it's only functorial with respect to simplicial maps, so you would have to try to take many compatible simplicial approximations. Who knows...

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Is the problem in your suggestion that we are working with cosimplicial *spaces* rather than  cosimplicial-simplicial sets? I'd be interested to know whether a theory of compactly supported cohomology (or BM homology) for such (appropriately nice/finite) gadgets existed.

Comment: in which way are cosimplicial spaces a problem over cosimplicial simplicial sets?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: in your comment your mentioned that locally finite chains were functorial only with respect to simplicial maps, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry, I meant simplicial maps between simplicial * complexes*

Comment: @FernandoMuro: OK, let's say I have a cosimplicial object in simplicial complexes, is there a functioning theory of compactly supported cohomology in this case? (I'm just trying to understand where the real obstacle lies and then work from there)